# Hidden div will not hide/show on radio button click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have two fields that are hidden. When a specific radio button is clicked I need the fields to appear. I am not sure why it is not working. I have included the code below.

html.erb file:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="mate-photo-label col-sm-4">
    <%= f.radio_button :check_request_type_id, '4' %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :check_request_type_id, 'Commission Invoice', value: '4', class: 'text' %>
  </div>
  <div class="mate-photo-label col-sm-4">
    <%= f.radio_button :check_request_type_id, '2' %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :check_request_type_id, 'Client Refund', value: '2', class: 'text' %>
  </div>
  <div class="mate-photo-label col-sm-4">
    <%= f.radio_button :check_request_type_id, '1' %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :check_request_type_id, 'Landlord Reimbursement', value: '1', class: 'text' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

html.erb file #2:

```
<div class="commission-fields" style="display: none;">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commission_collected, "Commission Collected", class: "general-text-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commission_collected, class: "general-text-field" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commission_percentage, "Your Commission Percentage", class: "general-text-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :commission_percentage, class: "general-text-field" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

js.file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($('input[value="4"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('#commission-fields').show();
    }
    else {
      $('#commission-fields').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: in your js, try `$(":input")` as seen [here](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: @NoamHacker That didn't work for me.

Comment: man, you are using `#` instead of `.` for the selector in your Jquery, that;s a class not an id.

Comment: @fanta Oh man, you are right. Is it Friday yet? Add that as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is un your jQuery selector to show hide your elements, change:

```
$('#commission-fields').show();
```

and

```
$('#commission-fields').hide();
```

to:

```
$('.commission-fields').show();
$('.commission-fields').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't have the links to the libraries for the jquery functions.

Try adding this in your header:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however that is not the issue. The jQuery CDN has already been added elsewhere.